# How to reconstruct 3D triangular meshes from points with SDF?

Tags: python, mesh, scikit-image, open3d

If I have 64 points with SDF([Signed distance function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function)) on 8x8 grid, I can reconstruct the isosurface by [Marching Cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes).
[image: Fig 1]

The question is:

If I only know the SDF of part of points(marked by orange squares as follow).

Can I reconstruct the isosurface?

If so, What should I do？

[image: Fig 2]

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Your illustrations make quite clear that it's impossible to construct the area if you don't know the SDF at certain points.

Comment: One thing that you could try is to estimate the SDF at the missing points based on the known values. For instance you can use RDFs (Radial Basis Functions) for interpolate and extrapolate the SDF. I have seen RDFs were used to reconstruct a surface from a number of known samples.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you share some references for these methods?@MauricioCeleLopezBelon

Comment: There are several references, one of the best ones to me is from Turk and O'Brien http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.2497&rep=rep1&type=pdf you will need to solve a single linear system to find the coefficients of the RBFs.

Comment: Thanks, Did you see any packages that can implement this algorithm? @MauricioCeleLopezBelon

Comment: John Burkardt's generic implementation seem to be good enough for your purpose https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/rbf_interp_nd/rbf_interp_nd.html